# Javascript Date function bug on EEST timezones

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, format

```
new Date("May 27, 2011, 1:00 pm EEST")
```

Firebug Response:

```
Date {Invalid Date}
```

Is this a known javascript bug ? how do you interpret the "Eastern European Summer Time" timezone in javascript with date ?

I can change the timezone to +03:00 or +0300 for example, but then it wouldn't be as friendly for the user, because im using the < abbr > tag and with jQuery i format each abbr innerHTML to what their title value is, so that when you hover over it, I still want the tooltip to display "May 27, 2011, 1:00 pm EEST", but in innerHTML i only need "May 27, 2011"

```
<abbr class="timestamp blue" title="May 27, 2011, 1:00 pm EEST">May 27, 2011</abbr>
```

However, because of EEST, i get this

```
<abbr class="timestamp blue" title="May 27, 2011, 1:00 pm EEST">NaN</abbr>
```

If i change EEST to something more common such as EST or GMT, then no problem, weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the ECMA-script specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format):

> There exists no international standard
>   that specifies abbreviations for civil
>   time zones like CET, EST, etc. and
>   sometimes the same abbreviation is
>   even used for two very different time
>   zones. For this reason, ISO 8601 and
>   this format specifies numeric
>   representations of date and time.

From [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)

> There are no time zone designators in ISO 8601. Time is only represented
>   as local time or in relation to UTC

In short: it's not a bug. You can't use zones like EEST and the like in the javascript Date object. You'll have to stick to 'UTC' or the +/- notation.

You can find a lot of information on the subject [@this webpage](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference)